# Passing Data From Parent to Child Component

Tags: angular

I need to pass the data from parent to child using input. The variable i would like to pass is coming from *ngFor.

I would like to do like this. Currently is not working; Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined

```
 <ul *ngFor="let item of data">
   <li> {{item.id}}</li>
 </ul>
 <ubi-story-side [rec]='item.id'></ubi-story-side>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ubi-story-side` is outside of the *ngFor and hence the item variable is unknown there. Which item do you want to pass to the story-side?

Comment: Thank you, i would like to pass (item.id). I put ubi-story-side inside of *ngFor and it works now. So, item is available here only in <ul>?

Comment: Yes, the `let item` defines a scope which is the `ul` element and its nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

creating @Inpust inside of child component

`child.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public rec: any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already did this part. My problem was getting undefined error when i tired to pass 'item' outside of <ul>

Comment: yes, `item` is only available in <ul> child element

Comment: Is it ok if i place child-selector inside of ngFor? In my question child selector is ubi-story-side. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: it depends what you have inside your child selector, but whatever inside your child component, it will duplicate by different item id `<li> {{item.id}} <ubi-story-side [rec]='item.id'></ubi-story-side> </li>`